# Removing specific html tags with python

Tags: python, html

I have some HTML tables inside of an HTML cell, like so:

```
miniTable='<table style="width: 100%%" bgcolor="%s">
               <tr><td><font color="%s"><b>%s</b></td></tr>
           </table>' % ( bgcolor, fontColor, floatNumber)

html += '<td>' + miniTable + '</td>'
```

Is there a way to remove the HTML tags that pertain to this minitable, and *only* these html tags?
I would like to somehow remove these tags:

```
<table style="width: 100%%" bgcolor="%s"><tr><td><font color="%s"><b>
and
</b></td></tr></table>
```

to get this:

```
floatNumber
```

where `floatNumber` is the string representation of a floating point number. *I don't want any of the other HTML tags to be modified in any way.* I was thinking of using string.replace or regex, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't install and use Beautiful Soup (otherwise BS is preferred, as @otto-allmendinger proposed):

```
import re
s = '<table style="width: 100%%" bgcolor="%s"><tr><td><font color="%s"><b>1.23</b></td></tr></table>'
result = float(re.sub(r"<.?table[^>]*>|<.?t[rd]>|<font[^>]+>|<.?b>", "", s))
```

Comment: For my app, this works great!  Otto's solution is also great if I could use Beautiful Soup

Answer (score 2):

[**Do not use str.replace or regex.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/92493)

Use a html parsing library like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), get the element you want and the contained text.

The final code should look something like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

for t in soup.find_all("table"): # the actual selection depends on your specific code
    content = t.get_text()
    # content should be the float number
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I'm using some proprietary developing environment, so I can't install and use Beautiful Soup

Comment: If the html code is well-formatted, you can also try using Python's built-in xml parsers.

Comment: Funny, but [BS4 uses `re` to parse XHTML](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L482). Do not use regex? Okay.

Comment: Also, if you only wish to remove predefined number of HTML tags, and do not want to parse attributes, build tree etc. why not use lightweight regex expression?

Comment: @fedosov you are linking to code used for parsing selectors, not for parsing XHTML

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger, oh, shame on me.